# Why do many commands provide a "quiet" option?

Tags: shell

Why do many commands provide the option `-q` or `--quiet` to suppress output when you can easily achieve the same thing by redirecting standard output to the null file?

Comment: I consider that mostly as a convenience flag.

Comment: Not all commands use `-q` to suppress *all* output. For example, Docker has a command to list images; `docker images` shows a formatted table with a bunch of information, while `docker images -q` outputs a plain list of image IDs (useful for piping to other commands).

Answer (score 75, accepted):

- While you can easily redirect in a shell, there are other contexts where it's not as easy, like when executing the command in another language without using a shell command-line. Even in a shell:

  ```
  find . -type f -exec grep -q foo {} \; -printf '%s\n'
  ```

  to print the size of all the files that contain `foo`. If you redirect to `/dev/null`, you lose both `find` and `grep` output. You'd need to resort to `-exec sh -c 'exec grep foo "$1" > /dev/null' sh {} \;` (that is, spawn an extra shell).
- `grep -q foo` is shorter to type than `grep foo > /dev/null`
- Redirecting to `/dev/null` means the output is still written and then discarded, that's less efficient than not writing it (and not allocate, prepare that output to be written)
- that allows further optimisations. In the case of `grep` for instance, since with `-q`, `grep` knows the output is not required, it exits as soon as it finds the first match. With `grep > /dev/null`, it would still try to find all the matches.
- *quiet* doesn't necessarily mean *silent*. For some commands, it means *reduce verbosity* (the opposite of `-v|--verbose`). For instance, `mplayer` has a `--quiet` and a `--really-quiet`. With some commands, you can use `-qqq` to decrease verbosity 3 times.

Comment: It's noteworthy that in the `grep` man-page both options, `-q`, and `-s`, are suggested to be avoided if portability is a concern. `grep`'s early exit is an important optimization, but not all programs with such options can do that; `curl -s` will still process the whole data (but the 3rd point still applies, thus saving processing time).

Comment: @Janis, that would be portability to very old systems. Both `-q` and `-s` are specified by POSIX. If we're to consider systems that old, then my `sh -c '...' sh {} \;` won't work either (with earlier `ksh`-based `sh`s).

Comment: The man page mentions: *USG-style grep also lacked -q but its -s option behaved like GNU grep.* - I thought that the difference in behaviour could be an issue. I can't judge about its relevance.

Comment: I frequently use the -q  and --quiet options when I only care about the return code of a command in a script.  The reasons noted above are even better examples why.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: you'd be amazed how (parts of) many systems are still that old... (well, actually, not that many ^^ but there are still some)

Comment: @Janis - it may be that the GNU `grep` manpage warning of `-q` portability concerns has another implication. Some readings of POSIX [`grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_04) pages, when considered alongside [Utility Description Defaults](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_04) might imply that `{ grep -q pattern; head; } <seekable_file` would print only the 10 lines following the first match for *pattern*. GNU `grep` won't do that *(not even when combined with its non-POSIX `-m1`)*.

Comment: mikeserv, is that a typo in your comment (using a semicolon instead of pipe inbetween the two processes)?

Comment: @Janis, no he's refering to `{ sed -n 2q; head -n 1; } < seekable_file` that should return the 3rd line as per POSIX (GNU sed doesn't), that is that `sed` should leave the cursor position just after the 2nd line. However, there's not such requirement for `grep -q` as POSIX doesn't mandate `grep` exits upon processing the first matching line.

Comment: Stéphane and @Janis - it isn't mandated that it exit, but the *Informative* section of the `grep` spec says it *can* - and I assume that is because many *do* - though I don't know of any. The Utility Defaults says that all standard utilities should leave the offset immediately following the last byte read when through. But the weird part about GNU `grep -q` is `grep -qm1` - where, for whatever reason, though they spec `-m1` to leave the offset after the matching line, adding the `-q` nullifies this.

Comment: And actually, Stéphane, I don't know. The `grep -q` verbiage *(Quiet... Exit with zero status if an input line is selected)* doesn't differ terribly from `sed q` *(Branch to the end of the script and quit without starting a new cycle).* When taken in context with mandated exit offset behavior *(When a standard utility reads a seekable input file and terminates without an error before it reaches end-of-file, the utility shall ensure that the file offset in the open file description is properly positioned just past the last byte processed by the utility)* I should think they'd behave similarly.

Comment: And `curl` has to receive the remainder of the stream for error detection reasons.

Answer (score 3):

It still allows for the command to put out when It feels it needs to a  note to the screen but normally it puts nothing out.  with redirecting all to null there is no chance for the output to be seen.

Comment: Well, quiet means that no response is expected; it would be unexpected if we'd see output anyway. (In case that there's anyway something "really really really" important to print (in a terminal attached process) a tty/pty device could directly be used by the process. An example for that may be interactive inquiry of a password, or somesuch.)

Answer (score 2):

Although it probably depends on the command, `-q` would also disable output to `stderr`. This allows shells that don't easily allow duping stderr to stdout (I'm looking at you, `csh` & `tcsh`) to avoid the noise.

Some programs provide a "quiet" option for situations where it may have other meaningful output that you don't want cluttered with status messages. The `-q` or equivalent would silence all program status output, allowing a pure data stream from, say, `tar` or `gzip`.

Answer (score 0):

Besides all the good responses and points above, it is a best practice to provide an opposite option for every flag. So, if there is `-v` for verbosity there should be `-q` for non-verbosity, quiet or silence. (This is not the point of discussion though...) There should be a long option for every short one as well, `-q` and `--quiet`.

As in almost everything in our business, there are many ways to get a solution or the same results. Having `-q` is one of them.